# Multiple versions of latex installed on mac

Tags: pdftex, installing, texmaker, mac, macports

I seem to have two versions of LaTeX installed on my mac, and it's causing problems because the most up to date version (one that has the right .sty files and packages for Rstudio and Jupyter notebooks), is not the default.

The one that works is installed in: /usr/texbin/

On loading it says "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)"

The additional version is installed in: /opt/local/bin/

It says "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_3)"

How can I uninstall the second version? I'm guessing MacPorts installed it at some point? I'm a bit worried about deleting it and then finding out there were dependencies. My main editor is TeXmaker and I believe it uses the /usr/texbin/ install, but are there things I could (potentially) screw up?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A different suggestion: Delete *both* versions of TeXLive2015 -- and install TeXLive2017 (or, if you can wait a few more days, TeXLive2018).

Comment: But in the short term, at least delete the MacPorts one.  The package manager should have a way to do that without hurting anything else, I think.

Comment: Until you find out how to remove the distribution installed by MacPorts you can add the line `PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH` at the bottom of your `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile` file(s). What OS version are you using? Recent versions no longer allow you to write to /usr so /usr/texbin doesn’t exist. With MacTe-2015 and later you can use /Library/TeX/texbin instead

Answer (score 1):

In `Applications/TeX/` you can find the *TeX Live Utility.app*. Open it and go to *Configure > Change Default TeX Live Version*.

This will open a window similar as:
[image]

So you can probably change from your MacPorts to the TeXLive version.

Comment: The problem is that, at least historically, MacPorts and Fink, have placed their paths BEFORE everything else in the PATH variable. That means a TeX Distribution  installed by MacPorts or Fink is found before the one at /usr/texbin or /Library/TeX/texbin is found.

Comment: This solves the problem if using TeXshop, but it may not work from the shell, pdflatex (pdftex, xelatex, etc.) may still call the old version. The fix is to tweak the $PATH command and put the directory of the latest version (where I'm reasonably assuming that's what you want to do).